# Selenium tests and continuous integration (Running browser in background)

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration

We have Xserver-less CentOS system for continuous integration. So no UI.

I want to run selenium test cases on it. I am using new Alpha version of Selenium2 which has WebDriver integration. It starts and ends browser by its own. Now, How do I start that in background? Something similar is possible with Internet Explorer?

I am able to run correctly on local machine. But it opens Firefox UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to run a virtual frame buffer? That way, all the GUI programs can believe there's graphics happening, even if there's no actual screen. You may wish to search for the term "headless". [One example.](http://www.alittlemadness.com/2008/03/05/running-selenium-headless/)

Another possibility may be to use [Celerity](http://celerity.rubyforge.org/) - a ruby-based "headless browser". It uses the [Watir](http://watir.com/) interface (originally a competitor to selenium), which I understand to be merging with webdriver.

Comment: Thanks for link. I had done this earlier but forgot how to use it. What about windows platform ? How so many projects do selenium testing for their UI ? Its strange..cos s many ppl use continuous integration and selenium. As far as i know continuous integration servers are does not really need X or UI. They are headless. There is so less documentation available for this.